# Data Catalog tables as sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I am trying to create a Crawler to scan S3 bucket Parquet files and update partition information of an existing table in Glue Data Catalog.

Here is the exact feature I am talking. 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws-glue-crawlers-now-support-existing-data-catalog-tables-as-sources/

Certainly working from console, however, I am not finding the option to provide Table name from DataCatalog when creating AWS::Glue::Crawler using cloudformation. Is this a feature that is not added to cloudformation or I can't find it in documentation.

Are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes folder name in s3 bucket as table name. You can add prefix by using `TablePrefix`.  But at this stage, there is no way to specify table name explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. I contacted AWS support and they did confirm that this is yet to be added to CF. I ended up doing similar. created the table with same name as what Crawler would create with similar parameters and let Crawler just update Partition info!